# Segmentation fault when running sphinx_fe -- strlen.S: No such file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm following the tutorial to adapt an acoustic model - https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialadapt/

When i ran the command:

```
sphinx_fe -argfile en-us/feat.params -samprate 16000 -c arctic20.fileids -di . -do . -ei wav -eo mfc -mswav yes
```

I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) message and the program exits. My laptop runs on Ubuntu 16.04.

gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
```

and backtrace:

```
#0 strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106

#1 0x00007ffff7815980 in printf_positional (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffd0d0,
format=format@entry=0x403fb0 "Sample rate %.1f does not match configured
value in file '%s'\n", readonly_format=readonly_format@entry=0, 
ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffd248,
ap_savep=ap_savep@entry=0x7fffffffcc68, done=57, nspecs_done=1,
lead_str_end=0x403fbc "%.1f does not match configured value in file
'%s'\n",work_buffer=0x7fffffffcca0 "@\315\377\377\377\177", save_errno=17,
grouping=0x0,thousands_sep=0x7ffff7955b25 "") at vfprintf.c:2023

#2 0x00007ffff78164a6 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffd0d0,
format=,format@entry=0x403fb0 "Sample rate %.1f does not match configured
value in file '%s'\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffd248) at vfprintf.c:1677

#3 0x00007ffff78df896 in ___vsnprintf_chk ( s=s@entry=0x7fffffffd260
"Sample rate 0.0 does not match configured value in file '\200\272\367\377
\177", maxlen=, maxlen@entry=1024, flags=flags@entry=1,
slen=slen@entry=1024,
format=0x403fb0 "Sample rate %.1f does not match configured value in file   
'%s'\n",
args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd248) at vsnprintf_chk.c:63

#4 0x00007ffff7ba80e8 in vsnprintf (__ap=0x7fffffffd248, __fmt=, 
__n=1024,
__s=0x7fffffffd260 "Sample rate 0.0 does not match configured value in
file '\200\272\367\377\177") at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:77

#5 err_msg (lvl=lvl@entry=ERR_ERROR, path=path@entry=0x403a09
"sphinx_fe.c", ln=137,
fmt=) at err.c:96

#6 0x00000000004023a7 in detect_riff (wtf=0x60a080) at sphinx_fe.c:137

#7 0x00000000004035bc in detect_audio_type (wtf=0x60a080) at
sphinx_fe.c:750

#8 sphinx_wave2feat_convert_file (wtf=wtf@entry=0x60a080, infile=,
outfile=0x61ecc0 "./arctic_0001.mfc") at sphinx_fe.c:792

#9 0x0000000000401a14 in run_control_file (ctlfile=, wtf=0x60a080)
at sphinx_fe.c:992

#10 main (argc=, argv=) at sphinx_fe.c:1032
```

Anyone has a sugestion for me how to fix it?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not problems running a program you downloaded. You should report this as a bug to the developer.

Comment: Note that the message `../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.` is coming from gdb, and has nothing to do with the segfault.

Comment: @Barmar you are right sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is kind of simple,

the tutorial dont mention that the wav-files should be in 16-Bit format.
(Since audacity by default use a 32-Bit format i had to change that for my wav-files)